# twitter bootstrap display current logged user label vertical aligned correctly in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, navbar

With the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7cbh/1/

What do we need to change in order to align correctly the navitems + the user label + logout button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons inside forms are tricky. Adding class `.pull-right` to the button will fix vertical alignment.

Comment: it didnt work...is there something else we needed to change? http://jsfiddle.net/n7cbh/3/

Comment: Wow. What browser are you using?

Comment: current chrome browser (21), its true with firefox it displays fine...but i needed to add margin-right to label...any way to do it using the twitter bootstrap classes instead of adding custom styles by hand? http://jsfiddle.net/cLWh9/2/ (with that i will tick your answer as the correct one)

Comment: in safari happens too, it seems a problem in webkit

Comment: I'm testing directly modifying the docs and the same issue appears. It seems that `navbar` forms doesn't accept `legend` and that `.navbar-text` only works with `<p>`. I keep trying...

Comment: I found a way that displays correctly in firefox + webkit browsers too:
http://jsfiddle.net/cLWh9/3/
or
http://jsfiddle.net/n7cbh/4/

Comment: Well... this way the username goes away from the button.